# Jensen-like averaging inequality on integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

Let $\mathbb{Z}^*=\mathbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\}$. Let $f:\mathbb{Z}^*\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a nondecreasing function such that $f(a+b)\leq f(a)+f(b)$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^*$.

Is it true that for all $k,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, we have $$f(k)\ge\frac{f(a_1)+\dots+f(a_n)}{2n}$$ for all $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{Z}^*$ with $a_1+\dots+a_n=kn$?

For $n=2$, this is true, since $f(k)\geq\frac{f(2k)}{2}\geq\frac{f(a_1)+f(a_2)}{4}$, where we use both conditions on $f$. For $n=1$ it is also true trivially.

Comment: How do you deduce $\frac{f(2k)}{2} \geq \frac{f(a_1)+f(a_2)}{4}$? You have $a_1+a_2=2k$, so $f(2k)=f(a_1+a_2) \leq f(a_1)+f(a_2)$...

Comment: It is because $f(2k)\geq f(a_1)$ and $f(2k)\geq f(a_2)$.

Comment: You seem to insist on using non-standard, confusing notations : to you ${\mathbb Z}^{*}$ contains $0$, while $*$ usually denotes the exclusion of $0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is true, even with strict inequality.

By induction we have $f(nk)\leq nf(k)$. Suppose that we round each $a_i$ up to the next multiple of $k$, say $b_i$, so $f(a_i)\leq f(b_i)$ where $b_i-a_i<k$. Since $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=kn$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i<2kn$. Thus,

$$\sum_{i=1}^nf(a_i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^nf(b_i)\leq f(k)\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b_i}{k}<2nf(k).$$

Answer (score 1):

The best I can do is with $n^2$ in the denominator.

By induction, $f(kn) \leq \underbrace{f(k)+\cdots+f(k)}_{n}$, so $f(k) \geq \frac{f(kn)}{n}$. as $f$ is nondecreasing, $f(kn) \geq f(a_i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. Hence $nf(kn) \geq f(a_1)+\cdots +f(a_n)$, and thus $f(kn) \geq \frac{f(a_1)+\cdots+f(a_n)}{n}$. Combining this with the previous inequality, $f(k) \geq \frac{f(a_1)+\cdots +f(a_n)}{n^2}$.